# Issue when space is the last character of a post data php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encoding, contenteditable

I'm trying to allow the moderators of my stream app modifying the data of an episode directly in the watch page using contenteditable, jquery and php. Everything works perfectly except when the field has spaces at the end;

As I found, the requests are correctly sent. But the last space is taking a two characters size on the server side which is not deleted using php `trim()`, so it's not received as a space anymore. All my data, pages and server are encoded into **utf-8**, so it's not really an encoding problem.

Using base64 encoding, I found that this character is "`Â` " (the space is included).

Did I do something wrong? the base code is the following, you can try it yourself:

**html:**

```
<section>
    <span id=kubi_synopsys>Some content and the space: </span>
</section>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#synopsys").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13){//press enter
        $("#synopsys").html($("#synopsys").text()) //removing new lines
        //posting data
        //#episode is a <data> tag containing the current episode's info
        $.post("synopsys-set.php",{
            series: $("#episode").data("series"),
            season: $("#episode").data("season"),
            episode: $("#episode").data("episode"),
            synopsys: $("#synopsys").text()
        },"json")
        .success(function(data){
            console.log("success",atob(data.response))
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("error")
        })
    }
})
```

**php:**

```
<?php
//acquisition
$series = isset($_POST['series'])? (int)$_POST['series'] :0;
$season = isset($_POST['season'])? (int)$_POST['season'] :0;
$episode = isset($_POST['episode'])? $_POST['episode'] :0;
$version = isset($_POST['version'])? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['version'])) :'';
$synopsys = isset($_POST['synopsys'])? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['synopsys'])) :'';

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('response'=> base64_encode($synopsys)));
```

Comment: Try removing unwanted characters? `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);`

Comment: @AnkitPise good idea, adding some accentuated letters, dot etc, this is what I want. Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@AnkitPise** said, `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 .-]/', '', $string);`, will remove all chars which doesn't have to be inside a normal text on the server-side, so this is what I want.

Plus, as **@Tushar** said, `String.trim()` solves it on the client side. No space, no bizarre char.

However, even if my problem is solved, does anyone know why it appears? Because some fields can't be as strict as a synopsys (plain text), and may contain some *exotic* chars, and in this case, using a regular expression would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing:

```
$("#synopsys").html($("#synopsys").text()) //removing new lines
```

As this is not required. Anyway, you're using `text()` on `#synopsys` when `post`ing data.

You can remove all the leading and trailing spaces using `trim()`.

```
synopsys: $("#synopsys").text().trim()
```

OR

You can use `regex` to remove all space characters(tabs, newlines, etc.)

```
synopsys: $("#synopsys").text().replace(/\s+/, ' ').trim()
```

Comment: Sure, this is doing the trick, but only only on the client-side. I want to do the same for server-side as well.

Comment: @PierreTassel Once you've trimmed all spaces from client-side, you don't need to do it again on server-side

Comment: I want to be able to change the episode's data using different sources, not only through a browser, and all the processing should be done for my particular case on the server-side